# Cant Login using SSH or Filezilla FTP

Tags: ssh, putty, linode, ftp

I had been using linode successfully for the last 3 months. The server OS is a Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

From a few hours, I am not able to login through SSH via putty. After I enter the username and password, putty throws a pop up error:

```
Server connection closed unexpectedly.
```

Also when I try from filezilla, I get an error Error:

```
Connection timed out Error: Could not connect to server
```

I had managed to login to putty and FTP about 16 hours ago. From about 8-10 hours I am facing this problem. I contacted the linode support, who tried a few things and finally said, your linode must be misconfigured. I haven't made any changes in configuration of linode. Can anyone suggest whats going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Could be lots of things.  Possibly a memory issue (unable to fork a new session).  Can you get a console session onto it via Linode?  Can you remotely reboot it?  Try those.

Comment: I have checked the CPU usage and its normal. Also I can access the console via the ajax Lish console. I have rebooted it as well, but it was of no use.